# Using cleveref to refer to a list of subfigures doesn't work

Tags: cleveref, subfig

I have a problem when using cleveref to cross-reference to a list of subfigures. References to a single subfigure work fine, but when trying to group them, something goes wrong. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{mwe}


\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[t]
        \centering
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image-a}\label{fig1a}}
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image-b}\label{fig1b}}
        \caption{Caption }
    \end{figure}
This works: \cref{fig1a}\\
This also works: \cref{fig1b}\\
But this doesn't: \cref{fig1a, fig1b}\\
\end{document}
```

And this is the output:

[image]

I obviously would like the last line to say: "fig. 1a and 1b". What should I to to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me, if I remove the space between the two labels:

`\cref{fig1a,fig1b}`

I seems like cleverref uses the space in the label.

Comment: Wow that's dumb. Thank you!